# How to get button component in Unity 2019.3

Tags: unity

I have a simple class attached to a button in Unity Canvas:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class AudioButtonPlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button button;
    void Start()
    {
        button =  gameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
    }
}
```

But on the line `button =  gameObject.GetComponent<Button>();` I get the following message:

```
GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Button' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface
```

How can I access the "Button" component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're using the wrong namespace.**

Instead of

```
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
```

do

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Everything else should already work when you change that.